# Why has IP version 15 already been reserved?

Tags: networking, ip, rfc, iana

I found that Internet Protocol (IP) version numbers are published by IANA. It refers to the following table.

https://www.iana.org/assignments/version-numbers/version-numbers.xhtml

| Decimal | Keyword | Version | Reference |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0-1 |  | Reserved | Jon_Postel, RFC4928 |
| 2-3 |  | Unassigned | Jon_Postel |
| 4 | IP | Internet Protocol | RFC791, Jon_Postel |
| 5 |  | Reserved (Historic) | RFC1819, SC589H |
| 6 | IPv6 | Internet Protocol version 6 | RFC8200 |
| 7 |  | Reserved (Historic) | RFC1475, RFC6814 |
| 8 |  | Reserved (Historic) | RFC1621, SC589H |
| 9 |  | Reserved (Historic) | RFC1347, SC589H |
| 10-14 |  | Unassigned | Jon_Postel |
| **15** |  | **Reserved** | **Jon_Postel** |

Looking carefully, I found that IP version 15 was reserved by Jon Postel. I already know the uses of the other versions, but I have never seen or heard of IP Version 15. Why is IPv15 reserved? What is its purpose?

Comment: Interesting question (even if it might be off-topic). Down the rabbit role (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jon_Postel)..

Comment: Thanks!Of course I know about Jon Postel. He was a great man who wrote the history of TCP/IP.

Comment: Since originally that field is only supposed to be a single bit https://www.rfc-editor.org/ien/ien26.pdf then quickly changed to 4 bit https://www.rfc-editor.org/ien/ien28.pdf and is the very beginning of the header, reserving 15 which would show up as 1111 might be to detect invalid packet.

Comment: I see, the version header is 4 bits, and 1111 in binary is 15 in decimal, so it may have a special meaning in finding invalid packets.